# Handle r.js error while spawning process in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, r.js

I've been trying to `spawn` a new child process running `require.js` optimizer `r.js` using the below code

```js
    var fs = require('fs');
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

    var prc = spawn('node', ['r.js', '-o', 'build.js']);

    prc.on('close', function(exitCode, signal) {
      if (exitCode) {
        console.log("something bad happened");
      }
      console.log("Exit Code is::-" + exitCode);
    });

    prc.on('exit', function(exitCode, signal) {
      if (exitCode) {
        console.log("something bad happened");
      }
      console.log("Child Process Exit with code::-" + exitCode);
    });

    prc.on('error', function(exitCode, signal) {
      if (exitCode) {
        console.log("something bad happened");
      }
      console.log("Error Occurred");
    });

    prc.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
      console.log('Caught exception during build: ' + err);
    });

    prc.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
      console.log( "stdout::-" + data );
    });

    prc.stderr.on("data", function(data) {
      console.log( "stderr::-" + data );
    });

    process.on("exit", function() {
      console.log("main Process is killed");
      console.log("Main process ID is::-" + this.pid);
    });
    process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
      console.log('Caught exception in parent process: ' + err);
    });
```

The child process spawned using above snippet always exit with exit code `0` even if `r.js` encounters some error. 
Running the same command `node r.js -o build.js` from console gives the exit code `1` when r.js encounters some error which helps to identify that the command was unsuccessful
1. How to detect the child process does not run successfully ?
2. If child process does not run successfully, how to kill parent process ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using the r.js `optimize` method directly? http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#optimizer

Comment: We are writing fairly complex application where we are having 60 -70 modules, each module is being developed by a dedicated team. Each team is using r.js optimizer individually. What I wanted to do is to take all modules `build_config.js` for optimizer and run them concurrently so that the entire build process becomes much more faster.